# Python-docx : Getting an extra paragraph when inserting it inside cell of table

Tags: python, docx

I'm working on generating a .docx document. When I insert a paragraph inside a cell I mean a cell of table, I get an extra paragraph(s), you can see it on this image[image]

Here is my code :

```
def personnalize_paragraph(p, alignment=False, text=None, font_size=0, bold=False, rgb=RGBColor(0x00, 0x00, 0x00)):
if alignment:
    p.alignment = alignment
p_run = p.add_run()
if text:
    p_run.text = text
if bold:
    p_run.bold = bold
if font_size:
    p_run.font.size = Pt(font_size)
if rgb:
    p_run.font.color.rgb = rgb
return p_run
```

And in "**main**" :

```
second_table = document.add_table(cols=1, rows=1)
shading_elm_1 = parse_xml(r'<w:shd {} w:fill="253E44"/>'.format(nsdecls('w')))
second_table.cell(0, 0)._tc.get_or_add_tcPr().append(shading_elm_1)
# first paragraph
p = second_table.cell(0, 0).add_paragraph()
personnalize_paragraph(p, WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT.CENTER, 'Carte d’identité du projet', 20, True,
                       RGBColor(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF))
# second paragraph
p = second_table.cell(0, 0).add_paragraph()
personnalize_paragraph(p, WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT.CENTER, 'project.project.acronym', 14, True,
                       RGBColor(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF))
# third paragraph
p = second_table.cell(0, 0).add_paragraph()
personnalize_paragraph(p, WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT.CENTER, 'Projet coordonné par le conseiller scientifique', 14,
                       True, RGBColor(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF))
# fourth paragraph
p = second_table.cell(0, 0).add_paragraph()
personnalize_paragraph(p, WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT.CENTER, 'project.project.managers_ids', 14, True,
                       RGBColor(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF))
```

Can you help me? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't need to add paragraph anymore because cell (object) already have it, watch this thread  [paragraph.run text in table cells](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/525)